# Need help on getting data from xml recursively

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am trying to read the data from following xml attributes recursively through XSLT.

This is my Sample XML data!!

```
<FIXML .....">
  <Batch ....>
    <MktDef MktID="XEUR" MktSegID="14" EfctvBizDt="2017-05-11" NxtEfctvBizDt="2017-05-15" MktSeg="CONF" MarketSegmentDesc="FUT 8-13 Y. SWISS GOV.BONDS 6%" Sym="CH0002741988" ParentMktSegmID="FBND" Ccy="CHF" MktSegStat="1" USFirmFlag="Y" PartID="2">
     .
     .
     .
    </MktDef>
    <MktDef MktID="XEUR" MktSegID="19629" EfctvBizDt="2017-05-11" NxtEfctvBizDt="2017-05-15" MktSeg="FBON" MarketSegmentDesc="EURO BONO FUTURE 8,5-10,5 YEAR" Sym="DE000A163W29" ParentMktSegmID="FBND" Ccy="EUR" MktSegStat="1" USFirmFlag="Y" PartID="2">
     .
     .
     .
     </MktDef>
     .
     .
     .
```

And this is my XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
 MktID,MktSegID,EfctvBizDt,NxtEfctvBizDt,MktSeg,MarketSegmentDesc,Sym,ParentMktSegmID,Ccy,MktSegStat,USFirmFlag,PartID
<xsl:for-each select="/">
<xsl:value-of select="concat(ancestor::FIXML/Batch/MktDef/@MktID,',',ancestor::FIXML/Batch/MktDef/@MktSegID,',',ancestor::FIXML/Batch/MktDef/@EfctvBizDt,',',ancestor::FIXML/Batch/MktDef/@NxtEfctvBizDt,',',ancestor::FIXML/Batch/MktDef/@MktSeg,',',ancestor::FIXML/Batch/MktDef/@MarketSegmentDesc,',',ancestor::FIXML/Batch/MktDef/@Sym,',',ancestor::FIXML/Batch/MktDef/@ParentMktSegmID,',',ancestor::FIXML/Batch/MktDef/@Ccy,',',ancestor::FIXML/Batch/MktDef/@MktSegStat,',',ancestor::FIXML/Batch/MktDef/@USFirmFlagt,',',ancestor::FIXML/Batch/MktDef/@PartID,'&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my Java code..

```
class Xml2Csv {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        File stylesheet = new File("style.xsl");
        //File xmlSource = new File("Testing-1.xml");
        File xmlSource = new File("95FILRDF01PUBLI20170511XEUR6NJ92000.xml");

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(xmlSource);

        StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(stylesource);
        Source source = new DOMSource(document);
        System.out.println(source.toString());
        System.out.println("Hello");
        Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(new File("MktDef.csv"));
        transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);

    }
}
```

I am  parsing this xml and trying to get the data from MktDef attributes and store it in CSV as follows,

```
MktID   MktSegID    EfctvBizDt  NxtEfctvBizDt   MktSeg  MarketSegmentDesc   Sym ParentMktSegmID Ccy MktSegStat  USFirmFlag  PartID
XEUR    14  5/11/2017   5/15/2017   CONF    FUT 8-13 Y. SWISS GOV.BONDS 6%  CH0002741988    FBND    CHF 1       2
XEUR    14  5/11/2017   5/15/2017   CONF    FUT 8-13 Y. SWISS GOV.BONDS 6%  CH0002741988    FBND    CHF 1       2
XEUR    14  5/11/2017   5/15/2017   CONF    FUT 8-13 Y. SWISS GOV.BONDS 6%  CH0002741988    FBND    CHF 1       2
XEUR    14  5/11/2017   5/15/2017   CONF    FUT 8-13 Y. SWISS GOV.BONDS 6%  CH0002741988    FBND    CHF 1       2
.
.
.
```

The problem I am facing right now is I am only getting the 1st MktDef data all the time. I understood that there is some logic problem in XSLT.

I am very new to working on XML and XSLT, so could you please anyone help me on this.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Where is the Java in all of this?

Comment: I Just added the java code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are inside of the template for the root node (`/`), then the XPath in the select of your for-each is relative from that node. You want to iterate over each of the `MktDef` elements, so it should be `FIXML/Batch/MktDef`.

Now, inside of your for-each, the context node changes to be the current `MkDef` element in each iteration. So, to get the value of the current `MktDef` element's attributes, you select relative from it: i.e. `@MktSegID`

Also, if you are emitting literal text, like your CSV header row, put it inside of `<xsl:text>` elements, so that you can use text formatting and indentation within your template and that whitespace is not seen as significant.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>MktID,MktSegID,EfctvBizDt,NxtEfctvBizDt,MktSeg,MarketSegmentDesc,Sym,ParentMktSegmID,Ccy,MktSegStat,USFirmFlag,PartID&#xA;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:for-each select="FIXML/Batch/MktDef">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(@MktID,',',@MktSegID,',',@EfctvBizDt,',',@NxtEfctvBizDt,',',@MktSeg,',',@MarketSegmentDesc,',',@Sym,',',@ParentMktSegmID,',',@Ccy,',',@MktSegStat,',',@USFirmFlagt,',',@PartID,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Hanse, Thank you for your Help. I am able to get all the data with your modified XSLT but there is one small issue. After getting column names, the 1st row of the data is coming besides to the column names. MktID,....MktSegStat USFirmFlag PartID XEUR 14 5/11/2017 5/15/2017 CONF. How to get this row in next line ?

Comment: For instance, I want a new line after </xsl:text>. So that the data we are extracting from for-each loop will get into the next line onwards. Can you please help on this. Thank you!

Comment: Whoops! I had left out the entity reference for the line ending in the header row